# Delete data from database using php and sql

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, mysqli

So I have a php page that looks like this

[image]

```php
<?php
    echo "<table border='1' width= 300px >
    <tr>
        <th>Friend Names</th>
        <th>Remove Friends</th>
    </tr>";
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $friend_id_got = $row['friend_id2'];
    
        $query3 = "SELECT profile_name 
                    from friends 
                    where friend_id = '$friend_id_got' ";
        $result3 = $conn->query($query3);
        $final3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $final3['profile_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" 
    ?>
        <form action="friendlist.php" method= "POST">
            <button id="add-friend-btn" type= 'submit' name = 'submit'>Unfriend</button>
        </form>
    <?php
  
        "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

When I press the button, I need the corresponding name to delete it. The only problem I'm facing is that How do I get the name corresponding to the button.
I think we need to relate the buttons and the name somehow, so when a specific button is pressed i get the corresponding name

Comment: Just add a hidden field to the form containing the ID (from `$friend_id_got`, I expect). It'll then be available in the $_POST data when you submit the form

Comment: U mean like an input field? Okay, But how do I get the name of which corresponding button is pressed.

Comment: I mean a _hidden_ field (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden). `But how do I get the name of which corresponding button is pressed`...you don't need the name of the button, you need the ID of the person being unfriended. That's what the hidden field would provide. That's what you would then use in your query to update the database. When you say the "name of the button", do you really mean "something to indicate that the action to be carried out is the "unfriend" action? If so, then another hidden field for that will do the trick.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: There are a couple of syntax errors in there that surely must be causing error messages! Is this the real running code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question and comments, and a glance at your code it sounds like you probably actually need two pieces of data to be submitted to the server when your button is clicked:

1. The action which should be undertaken in response to the request (i.e. unfriending)
2. The ID of the person being unfriended

To achieve that you can add some hidden fields to your form. These are invisible to the user but will be available to PHP in the `$_POST` data when the form is submitted.

Something like this:

```
<form action="friendlist.php" method= "POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="unfriend_id" value="<?=$friend_id_got ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="unfriend" />
  <button id="add-friend-btn" type="submit" name= "submit">Unfriend</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comment from @ADyson:

```
<form action="friendlist.php" method= "POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_id" value="<?=$friend_id_got ?>" />
    <button id="add-friend-btn" type="submit" name="submit">Unfriend</button>
</form>
```

By including a hidden field in the form, you're able to store more information.

You can see that I'm storing the ID of the friend you're unfriending in the value of the hidden field, so when the form is submitted (the button is clicked) you'll have access to "cancel_id" in the POST data, which will obviously contain the ID of the friend to unfriend.